# input event not working on bootstrap datepicker textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have customized the bootstrap datepicker. I want to show an alert while the start date is selected. here is my code.

```
<div class="  input-daterange input-group" id="datepicker">
<input type="text" class="input-sm form-control" name="from" id="startdate" placeholder="From date" value="04/06/2018" />
<span class="input-group-addon">to</span>
<input type="text" class="input-sm form-control" name="to" id="enddate" placeholder="To date" value="04/10/2018" />
```

```
$(document).on('input','#startdate',function () { 
alert('h');
});
```

also, I add datepicker to both the textbox elements. my input event is not working.

anyone help me, please.

Answer (score 0):

do something like this:

```
$(document).on('change','#startdate',function () { 
alert('h');
});
```

As per your comment you can try like:

```
$('#startdate').on('change','#startdate',function () { 
alert('h');
});
```

Comment: yes, it's working but a alert show on page load for first time how to stop that.